# How to protect P-MOSFET from excessive gate voltage

Tags: relay

I would like to build a DIY solid state relay for my car to enable some circuits (less than 1A current absorption) only when the accessories are powered up (independently from engine on or off).

I have some spare IRF4905 P-MOSFET, some optocouplers, some TVS diodes 18V and various Zeners.

My idea was this one (I found no optocoupler in Circuitlab, I made it myself more or less). I omit from the schematic the diode protecting from inverse voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvhvU1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

IRF4905 accepts at most Vgs=20V. In a car I could get short spikes higher than that. Hoe can I protect it using a 18V TVS diode or various Zener I have?

An idea could be to do this, since the IRF4905 requires only 4V of Vgs for complete turn-on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRssun.png)</sup>

Would that work? other ideas? Or should I really use a traditional mechanical relay?

Comment: IMo the first circuit with zener is OK. One other concern is that you can get high voltage spikes on output, when some other inductive load kicks back, this can be solved usin avalanche rated MOSFET, that starts conducting even in opposite if the voltage is higher than avalnache breakdown voltage, so the MOSFET doesn't suffer the breakdown voltage.

Comment: Well the electrical circuit of the car has already somewhere else a TVS diode at 24V (I put it myself as part of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/225315/would-this-circuit-cut-power-to-the-cigarette-lighter-socket-effectively ), so I know I shouldn't get more than 24V as Vbatt. And against reverse I have a diode (I forgot to mention it, I added it now to the explanation).

Comment: Since you already have a 24V TVS, you could omit the Zener because the resistor divider won't reduce the voltage below 12V. But better safe than sorry.

Comment: IMO, want to build a switch + diode circuit. NMOSFET, since having lower Rds are more suitable that PMOSFET + diode, but requires a charge pump, not easy to DIY. In case you don't want spend time to diy, I have found a circuit, didn't bougt it yet (same problematics, I want to turn off loads)  here the LTC4359 is ideal diode + switch circuit: http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/LTC4359-ideal-diode-Solar-energy-Charge-prevent-reverse-irrigation-Relay-freeshiping/1775761_32439044075.html

Comment: Datasheet:http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/4359fb.pdf, you will also find various gate protection circuits, maybe it will help you for your DIY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zener idea is a good one. If you can sacrifice turn on time, and your only dealing with short transient pulses on the supply side, then maybe adding a capacitor on the gate might be another way (it will slow things down) to stop transients, especially short ones. An inductor in series with R2 could accomplish a simmilar thing assuming the pules are short and you can deal with a slower turn on time.

An Solid State Relay is essentially the same thing, there are some constraints that come with them (resistance, some have a voltage drop) but they also have isolation and some have robust inputs with protection.

Comment: Inductors are difficult to come by by chance in my toolbox, and even if I have some of hem and also a Victor VC9805A+ with inductance meter (a Chinese one), they are still difficult to measure. I'll probably go for the capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

> Would that work? other ideas?

In the 2nd circuit I would make R3 much lower than R2 or you will be naturally reducing the drive voltage to the gate under normal conditions and this will result in higher on resistance in the MOSFET.

I say this because the CTR of the opto may be 50% (for example) and this would mean only about 1 mA flowing into the collector. Peak loads may far exceed average load currents as well so getting a few more volts driving the MOSFET isn't a bad idea.

Comment: How do you get that exactly? -4V gth P-mos gate driven at -6V source voltage?

Comment: @Barleyman optimum on-resistance occurs at Vgs = 15V although 10V aint too bad but 6V may not be sufficient for some loads. I know the op says 1A but who knows what the peak value might be. Also given the CTR of the opto every bit of drive voltage that can be maximized should be.

Comment: I agree. R3 could be as low as 100 ohms and still no chance of parasitic oscillation. M1 is ok if no severe voltage spikes on the 12 volt line, if M1 is in an OFF state. I would put a .1uF cap across the Vkey input to dampen contact noise.

Comment: Ah the fool me, taking OP word for it without checking datasheet. However with ~50A capacity at 6V, I think it can drive 1A load without too much effort..

Comment: @Sparky256 100 ohm on R3 means that for a 24V spike (6V on it) I would get 0.36W dissipation, I would need 1/2W resistor. Better use >470 ohm to use the common 1/8W or 1/4W resistors.

Comment: @Sparky256 in OFF state there are no spikes... the OFF state happens only when voltage is very low (like during engine startup) and when the key is not inserted, so no electronic stuff is turned on. Spikes come mostly from spark ignition (I guess).